# Parametized sql query with two parameters one of which is a collection of lists

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, sqlite

I have large databases for which I am using an sql query in python to write the data to csv files. In the sql database each row is a series of spatial information for a finger ID. I can parametize the query for to get the information and write the files I need for each finger. However, the problem arises in creating a functional for loop that iterates over each ID for all the indexes in the list.

```
INDEX = ([44,48,50,55,56,57], [49,54,57,61,62,64])


FINGER = ('rt100', 'rt101')

d = {}
for Y,X in FINGER, INDEX:
    d[Y] = pd.read_sql ("SELECT x,y, CAST( (direction*180/3.142)as INT),CAST(quality*100 as INT) from UTS_7_fingerprints where finger like ? and ind = ?", conn, params=(Y,X,))
```

This is the code I have currently, however I get this error:

```
pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT x,y, CAST( (direction*180/3.142)as INT),CAST(quality*100 as INT) from UTS_7_fingerprints where finger like ? and ind = ?': Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

Even using trying the loop for a single ID and a single list of indexes I get the error that there are too many values to unpack.
I can't seem to find a way to include a list of lists within the SQL statement.

To be clear as to what I'm trying to do. I need to iterate through ID's such as 'rt100' for each Index in the lists ' [44,48,50,55,56,57]' and getting the data 'SELECT x,y, CAST( (direction*180/3.142)as INT),CAST(quality*100 as INT)' for each Index and ID.
This produces a .csv file that looks like this:

```
372,402,281,83
394,303,303,97
415,422,123,86
458,328,292,95
464,487,112,96
483,389,303,95
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need every combination of FINGER and INDEX element then you shoud do something like:

```
for Y in FINGER:
    for X in INDEX:
        for x in X:
            d[Y] = pd.read_sql ("SELECT x,y, CAST( (direction*180/3.142)as INT),CAST(quality*100 as INT) from UTS_7_fingerprints where finger like ? and ind = ?", conn, params=(Y,x))
```

(note the small `x` in `params`)

**UPDATE** as per comments below:

```
for i,Y in enumerate(FINGER):
    for x in INDEX[i]:
        d[Y] = pd.read_sql ("SELECT x,y, CAST( (direction*180/3.142)as INT),CAST(quality*100 as INT) from UTS_7_fingerprints where finger like ? and ind = ?", conn, params=(Y,x))
```

Also in your code, d[Y] will be overwritten with each call to read_sql for the individual x's, so you may probably want to use something like `d[Y,x] = ...`.

Comment: Thank you for this, its a step closer. Apologies if my original post is unclear but I need the INDEX for each FINGER not all combinations. For example INDEX = [44,48,50,55,56,57] for finger 'rt100' and INDEX = [49,54,57,61,62,64] for FINGER 'rt101'. So each FINGER element has a separate and individual INDEX list to iterate through. In reality I have a much larger list of FINGER and their corresponding INDEX list.

Comment: The script you've suggested returns dataframes for all the INDEX where the values exist in the databases, as opposed to just the six values in each list per finger. Do you know of a way to limit the loop to use only the 6 values in each list and run them in parallel. So the 1st INDEX list runs for the 1st FINGER and 2nd INDEX for 2nd FINGER and so on?

Comment: @mattp Hope I understood you correctly this time, if not just give an explicit list of paramters for each call.